# Using javascript plugin in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I inherited an angularjs (so 1.5) codebase, I don't know all too much about angular so I'm wondering:

### I have an emoji picker plugin I want to implement (in vanilla js)

But how do I combine that code with Angular?

This is the code to initialize the plugin

```
import EmojiPicker from "rm-emoji-picker";

const picker = new EmojiPicker();
const icon      = document.getElementById('my-icon');
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const editable  = document.getElementById('my-input');

picker.listenOn(icon, container, editable);
```

#### What I've tried

Add that Code to a separate javascript file and include it above the AngularJS script tags, that is returning the following error

> Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null

#### AngularJS

There is the app.run.js file which has a Run method, in there, there's a lot of declarations, but how do I initialize the vanilla plugin in this case?

```
(function (){
"use strict";

angular
    .module('app')
    .run(Run);

Run.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$state', 'AuthenticationService'];
function Run($rootScope, $state, AuthenticationService) {
  // include it here?
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/kimooz/ng-emoji-picker, is an angular directive for your navtive lib

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried that one, I didn't get it to work, the documentation is incomplete, it's not clear which files to include etc. It's hard if you're new in angularjs.